# Thymeleaf href inside form going to different page

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm trying to implement a cancel button that takes you to the "home" page.  However, it tries to submit to the controller defined in the `th:action` of the `form` instead of the `th:href`.  Is there way to implement this cancel button without defining a mapping in the controller?

```
<form th:action="@{/manageUser}" method="post">
  <div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <a href="index.html" th:href="@{/}">
      <button name="cancel">Cancel</button>
    </a>
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

I get the following:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Parameter conditions ... not met for actual request parameters
```

The `th:href` works fine if it's outside of the form element

Comment: You just need to change the button type to button `<button type="button" name="cancel">Cancel</button>`. It defaults to submit

Comment: @123 good catch.  I thought the default was button.  If you submit as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you insist on using `<button>` element try this:

```html
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
<button type="button">
    <a href="/">Cancel</a>
</button>
```

You could also use the `<a>` element without `<button>` and style it in CSS if you want:

```html
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
<a href="/">Cancel</a>
```